# Running a job on CPU by default, but on GPU when available in Slurm

Tags: gpu, cpu, slurm

Is there a way to submit a job to Slurm with sbatch and use the gpu if available, but run on cpu if there is no gpu available?

Setting: `#SBATCH --gres=gpu:1` only runs on nodes where a gpu is available.
Omitting it or setting it to 0 never makes a gpu available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is unfortunately no direct solution in Slurm for this use case. A workaround can be to submit two jobs, one with `--gres` and the other without, and

- naming them `--job-name` identically
- setting `--dependency=singleton` on both
- inserting `scancel --jobname <chosen job name> --state PENDING` at the top of the submission script

The above configuration will make sure only one job can be started by Slurm, and as soon as one starts, it cancels the other.